# BibLaTeX not working with MikTeX, TeXMaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, errors, miktex, texmaker

I am using the latest version of both MikTeX and TexMaker (fresh install about two weeks ago). I am getting very frustrated because I am completely unable to use BibLatex in any of my documents. Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes,textcomp}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[backend=biblatex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citelist.bib}

\title{An examination of two dimensional direct and indirect excitons}
\author{Matthew Brunetti}

\begin{document}
...
Words.~\cite{zaslow2d}
...
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My citelist.bib has the correct form:

```
@article{zaslow2d,
    author =    "Zaslow, B.",
    author =    "Zandler, Melvin E.",
    title =     "Two-Dimensional Analog to the Hydrogen Atom",
    journal =   "Am. J. Phys.",
    year =      "1966"
}
```

....

It should also be noted that typing `\cite{`  **does** cause TexMaker to bring up an autocomplete form with all of my citation entries that can be found in citelist.bib. Also, I have tried using both the biber and biblatex backends with no success. I have used the MikTex package manager to install and update the Biblatex package and the biber package.

When I try to build the PDF using pdflatex + biblatex + pdflatex x2, I receive I multitude of errors, including, "use of sort list doesn't match its definition", on the line containing `\end{abstract}`, multiple "undefined control sequence. " on a line containing \begin{eqnarray}`, warnings that my citations are undefined (even though, as I said, TexMaker knows they're there and offers to autocomplete them for me), "warning: empty bibliography", and so on.

Is Biblatex simply not compatible with TexMaker and MikTex on Windows 10? How can I fix this?

EDIT: I have made the changes found in the three comments below but am still unable to compile the document. Here is the beginning of the document:

```
    \documentclass[]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{csquotes,textcomp}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }

    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sortlist=nty]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{citelist.bib}

    \title{(Title)}
    \author{(name)}

    \begin{document}
    \nocite{*}

    \maketitle

    \begin{abstract}
```

And at the bottom I have:

```
    \printbibliography{citelist.bib}  (line 315)

    \end{document}
```

When I run *only* Biber, using the directions found in (this link)[[Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations]), the process runs normally. When I try to then quick build with pdflatex + biblatex + pdf latex X2, I get the following errors:
        package keyval error: sortlist undefined
        [many equation cross references undefined]
        line 315: empty bibliography
        please rerun biber on the file: (biblatex) "(name of this file)" (biblatex) and rerun latex afterwards

I still do not understand what I'm doing wrong, or why these errors are appearing and how to fix them. Please help. I've been struggling with this for almost a week and it's driving me insane.

EDIT 2: My document compiles and displays PDF output when I run the following MWE at [sharelatex.com](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/570eb22d211d0aab16f05928). I still get the error message about the keyval package which still makes no sense to me.

EDIT 3: I will be posting (what I hope to be) relevant data from my .log file, found below:

```
    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
    Package: biblatex 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.sty
    Package: biblatex_ 2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber)                 (PK/JW/A
    B)

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
    Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options         (HO)

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
    Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.dbx' not found.
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.

    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
    File: blx-compat.def 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
    )
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex_.def' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex_.def
    File: biblatex_.def 
    \c@textcitecount=\count285
    \c@textcitetotal=\count286
    \c@textcitemaxnames=\count287
    \c@biburlnumpenalty=\count288
    \c@biburlucpenalty=\count289
    \c@biburllcpenalty=\count290
    \c@smartand=\count291
    )
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'numeric'...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
    File: numeric.bbx 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
    File: standard.bbx 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
    \c@bbx:relatedcount=\count292
    \c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count293
    ))
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
    File: numeric.cbx 2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
    Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
    )
    Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
    Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

    (c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
    File: biblatex.cfg 
    )

    *File List*
    biblatex.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
    biblatex_.sty    2016/03/03 v3.3 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
    biblatex-dm.cfg
    blx-compat.def    2016/03/03 v3.3 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
    biblatex_.def
```

FINAL EDIT: Thanks to everyone who tried helping me with this. I understand why this question should be closed since I changed my LaTeX distribution from miktex to texlive. I have all but abandoned BibLaTeX in favor of the `amsrefs` package and the `bibdiv` environment. It worked with no issues on my first try and appears to have all the same functionality as `biblatex` claimed, specifically self-contained bibliography files and organized citation entry with simple reference keys.

Again, thanks for all your help. Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There are some visible errors in your code, without even having to compile. First, `biblatex` is not a backend, it's only a package. The backend has to be either `biber` or `bibtex`. Second, don't load `eqnarray`, it's obsolete and results in bad spacing. Third you should load te language as an option of the document class, and just write `\usepackage{babel}`.

Comment: As above, you need to correct the code. Then you probably need to remove all generated files from your working directory produced by Biber/Biblatex. Then recompile. The error looks to be the result of using newer versions of the software with stale generated files.

Comment: If you have installed Biber on your machine and everything is up to date (you have done updates with both the User and Admin Updater) you need to use `backend=biber` and not `backend=biblatex` as already noted twice and make sure that your editor is configured to run Biber, see [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). And as cfr notes, it is a good idea to clear the temporary files (`.bbl`,`.bcf`) before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments, I have removed entirely the `backend=` option as the default is biber anyway. Within my Texmaker configuration the command for Biblatex was `biber %`, but I followed the link provided by moewe and now the command in that line specifies the full path for biber.exe found within my miktex 2.9 folder. I have cleaned my TexFiles folder of all generated files and I'm going to give it another shot. Fingers crossed, and thanks again. Here's hoping this works.

Comment: Another question actually, the link that moewe provides gives instructions on how to configure a stand alone biber compiler in TexMaker. Is that something I need to do within my citelist.bib file so that it is recognized within my actual .tex document?

Comment: As for the .log file, I'm assuming you're only interested in the version numbers of the biblatex and related packages. There's a lot of information in there and I don't exactly know what is important and what isn't, but I hope I got everything. Check the main post (EDIT 3) for a list of the relevant info.

Comment: Also Kurt I should mention that after finding other links on SE suggesting that Miktex itself may be interfering with the compiling of biblatex, I uninstalled Miktex and installed Texlive. So, I am now using Texlive (but still with the Texmaker frontend).

Comment: Uninstalling MikTeX is a bit radical (I never had big problems with it), but OK. Do you get any errors or warnings in your `.log` file? The above snippet seems fine. What does the `.blg` say after you ran Biber? Have you configured the quick build option to actually run Biber, or do you only have the standalone version set up? If you only have the standalone version you will have to run that by hand, but I doubt it will work if quick build runs BibTeX. Check the configuration again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op deinstalled the MiKTeX distribution. Now the described error can not be examinied longer ...