# Biber, error message at File.pm line 151

Tags: biber

I have a php script test.php which invokes latex+biber:

```
`/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/latex  --interaction batchmode test.tex `;
`/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/biber  test`;
```

The script works fine if I run it from terminal `php test.php` (as root); it does not work when it is called from a browser `http://localhost/test.php`. In the latter case, I understand it is called from user apache. (I am testing on a Linux  Fedora 29 machine).

The issue turns out to be related with `biber':

```
[root@fedora-pc]# su -s /bin/bash apache
bash-4.4$ /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/biber test
Can't open test.blg (Permission denied) at /tmp/par-617061636865/cache-975de9a2a2c44ccaa5329d9695a54026ffc29f68/inc/lib/Log/Log4perl/Appender/File.pm line 151.
```

Also, I just discovered that

```
[root@fedora-pc 2019]# /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --list
/usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.x86_64-linux: (stdin): Unexpected end of input

[root@fedora-pc 2019]# tlmgr update --self
/usr/local/texlive/2016/tlpkg/installer/xz/xzdec.x86_64-linux: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr: checksum error when downloading /tmp/WQEchRh21D/TzyO2wJ8pA from http://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb: digest disagree
```

I am not so knowledgeable about LaTex to know what is going on and how to fix it. (biber is version 2.9)

Comment: It looks as though Biber is not allowed to write its log file (the `.blg`). If I'm not mistaken, Biber will try to write the `.blg` in the current working directory. Not sure what that would be in your case, but it might be in a place where you have no write permissions. The other errors have nothing to do with Biber and are TeX live infrastructure-related. TeX live 2016 is frozen and doesn't get any updates any more (just about current is TeX live 2018, TeX live 2019 should be released around May).

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the LaTeX run works properly, I would have expected it to face similar permission issues with the `.log` file and all the auxiliary files. It should be noted, though, that Biber unpacks its executable into a temporary directory (in your case `/tmp/par-617061636865/cache-975de9a2a2c44ccaa5329d9695a54026ffc29f68/`) and runs from there. If programs in that path are restricted compared to programs in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/` and elsewhere (and it might not be unreasonable to apply such restrictions), that could explain things.

Comment: Related question on Windows: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/406960/35864. There it turned out that Bitdefender was blocking Biber (maybe even due to a heuristic that took issue with executables coming from a temporary folder).

Comment: @moewe LaTeX run works properly. How do I check whether 'programs in that [tmp] path are restricted'?

Comment: Sorry, no idea, that would be more of a Linux question than a LaTeX question, I guess.

Comment: the Tex/Biber questions is whether or not I may configure Biber as not to run from /tmp/

Comment: Also,  I just discovered that if I change owner of the /tmp/par/ directory to apache, and run biber as root, I just get _.../biber: private subdirectory /tmp/par-726f6f74 is unsafe (please remove it and retry your operation)_.

Comment: Biber uses `PAR::Packer` to unpack, apparently there is an environment variable to change the cache location: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=709846. Re your error message: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1058025

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not go into Perl. I would hope just to pass a different option to Biber.

Comment: I am not aware of any Biber option you could use, sorry. In https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70 the Biber developer mentions `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` himself, so I guess this is the intended interface.

Comment: do you happen to know how I  could  set PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP to my web server folder?

Comment: `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` should be a normal [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). It can be set and read like other variables such as `PATH`, `HOME `, `TEMP`, ... If and how this can be done will depend on your server and your rights (but I would not know anything about that, I'm afraid).

Comment: If you found a solution, please post a proper answer in the answers section and accept it so others can find it more quickly and benefit from it as well. (Personally, I think it should not be necessary to run Biber with root rights, but that there should instead be a way to redirect its temporary folder to a place where a normal user has read and write permissions, but I would not know how to do that.)

Comment: Hi, **I fixed it!** In the sudoers file I added line `apache ALL=(ALL:ALL)  NOPASSWD:/...path.../biber`; hence within the php script I call `biber` by `sudo -u root  /..path.../biber   bibFile`. The trick is to `sudo` on root ([thanks](https://superuser.com/questions/120208/how-to-give-apache-rights-to-run-svn-update/120209#120209)) . I note that the latter is not needed to call (pdf)latex.  I have set `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP` to `/var/www/tmp/` too, but it does not help. Also, Biber does not sem to unpack its executable when called as above, it does when called from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Fedora 29, 4.19.12-301.fc29.x86_64;
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (I updated)

I fixed my issue when I added the following line to the sudoers file:

```
apache ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/biber
```

My script `test.php` is:

```
<?php

$NomeFile = 'test';
$bibFile = $NomeFile;
$texFile = $NomeFile.".tex";
$pdfFile = $NomeFile.".pdf";
$f=fopen($texFile,'w');

            $header ="\\documentclass{article} \n ";
            $header.="\\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} \n ";
            $header.="\\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \n ";
            $header.="\\usepackage[american,italian]{babel} \n ";
            $header.="\\usepackage[babel,italian=guillemets]{csquotes} \n ";
            $header.="\\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}\n";
            $header.="\\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} \n ";

            $header.= "\\bibliography{".$bibFile."}";
            $header.="\\begin{document} \n ";

            $f=fopen($NomeFile.'.tex','w');
            fputs($f,$header);

fputs($f,"\\cite{Mario}"); 
$printbib = '\\printbibliography';
fputs($f,$printbib);
fputs($f,"\\end{document}");
fclose($f);

$filenameTeX = $NomeFile.'.tex'; 
$test_2 = `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex  --interaction batchmode $texFile `;
$test_3 = `sudo -u root /usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/biber  $bibFile `;
$test_4 = `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex  --interaction batchmode $texFile `;

$filenamePdf = $NomeFile.'.pdf'; 
echo "2 <pre>$test_2</pre>";
echo "3 <pre>$test_3</pre>";
echo "4 <pre>$test_4</pre>";
echo "<br><a href=\"$filenamePdf\">$filenamePdf</a>";
echo "<br><a href=\"$filenameTeX\">$filenameTeX</a>";
?>
```

my .bib file

```
@BOOK{Mario,
  author =      {Mario Doe},
  title =       {TITLE},
  publisher =   {My Pubblisher},
  location =    {World},
  year =        {2025} 
 }
```

I have set `PAR_GLOBAL_TEMP=\var\www\tmp` too, `tmp` owned by user `apache`, but it did not help.

A call from my browser `http://localhost/test.php` produces the wished `test.tex`  and `test.pdf` files, bibliography included. `/var/www/tmp/` remains empty. The same if I try by either `[root@....]# php test.php` or

```
[root@...]# su -s /bin/bash apache
bash-4.4$ php test.php
```

Note, if later I compile the .tex file, then `/var/www/tmp/` gets polluted by a number of files, mainly within a `inc` sub-directory.

I am not sure this is the best solution, still it works for me, on a local settings.