# Biber in Texmaker is not working

Tags: errors, biber

I run the code and I receive the following error:

> Process started
>
> No such file or directory at /loader/HASH(0x25b3a68)/PAR.pm line 1137.
>
> Process exited with error(s)

What can I do?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[style=apa,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text is here.
\textcite{Akaike1973}
\textcite{Akaike1987}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

`ref.bib`

```
@InProceedings{Akaike1973,
   author = {H. Akaike},
   title = {Information theory and an extension of the maximum likelihood principle},
   editor = {B. N. Petrov and F. Csaki},
   booktitle = {2nd International Symposium on Information Theory},
   pages = {267-281},
   year = {1973},
   location = {Budapest: Akademiai Kiado} 
}

@article{Akaike1987,
   author = {Akaike},
   title = {Factor analysis and AIC},
   journal = {Psychometrika},
   volume = {52},
   number = {3},
   pages = {317-332},
   year = {1987}
}
```

`.log` file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.11.18)  18 NOV 2019 21:56
entering extended mode
**./test.tex (test.tex LaTeX2e <2019-10-01    patch level 3 ("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls" Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo" File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81 \c@subsection=\count82 \c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84 \c@subparagraph=\count85 \c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102 ) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic\babel\babel.sty" Package: babel 2019/10/15 3.35 The Babel package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\babel\switch.def" File: switch.def 2019/10/15 3.35 Babel switching mechanism )
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
* ("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/arabi\bblopts.cfg" File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of  babel )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\amer ican.ldf" Language: american 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/babel-english\engl ish.ldf" Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system  ("C:\Program
Files\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic\babel\babel.def" File: babel.def 2019/10/15 3.35 Babel common definitions \babel@savecnt=\count88 \U@D=\dimen103

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\babel\txtbabel.def") \bbl@dirlevel=\count89 ) \l@canadian = a dialect from
\language\l@american  \l@australian = a dialect from
\language\l@british  \l@newzealand = a dialect from
\language\l@british  )))
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes. sty" Package: csquotes 2019-11-15 v5.2h context-sensitive quotations (JAW)

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/etoolbox\etoolbox. sty" Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW) \etb@tempcnta=\count90 )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.st y" Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks14 ) \csq@reset=\count91
\csq@gtype=\count92 \csq@glevel=\count93 \csq@qlevel=\count94
\csq@maxlvl=\count95 \csq@tshold=\count96 \csq@ltx@everypar=\toks15

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes. def" File: csquotes.def 2019-11-15 v5.2h csquotes generic definitions (JAW) ) Package csquotes
Info: Trying to load configuration file 'csquotes.cfg'... Package
csquotes Info: ... configuration file loaded successfully.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/csquotes\csquotes. cfg" File: csquotes.cfg  )) ("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex. sty" Package: biblatex 2019/08/31 v3.13a programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\pdftexc mds.sty" Package: pdftexcmds 2019/07/25 v0.30 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO )

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\infware rr.sty" Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifluatex.s ty" Package: ifluatex 2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty" Package: iftex 2019/11/07 v1.0c TeX engine tests )) ("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\ltxcmds .sty" Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO) )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty" Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead. ) Package pdftexcmds Info:
LuaTeX not detected. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is
available. Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found. )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/oberdiek\kvoptions .sty" Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\kvsetke ys.sty" Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/generic/oberdiek\etexcmd s.sty" Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO) )))
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.sty" Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger \lrq@indent=\count97
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/logreq\logreq.def" File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0 )) ("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty " Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC) )
("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/url\url.sty" \Urlmuskip=\muskip10 Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc. ) \c@tabx@nest=\count98
\c@listtotal=\count99 \c@listcount=\count100 \c@liststart=\count101
\c@liststop=\count102 \c@citecount=\count103 \c@citetotal=\count104
\c@multicitecount=\count105 \c@multicitetotal=\count106
\c@instcount=\count107 \c@maxnames=\count108 \c@minnames=\count109
\c@maxitems=\count110 \c@minitems=\count111 \c@citecounter=\count112
\c@maxcitecounter=\count113 \c@savedcitecounter=\count114
\c@uniquelist=\count115 \c@uniquename=\count116
\c@refsection=\count117 \c@refsegment=\count118
\c@maxextratitle=\count119 \c@maxextratitleyear=\count120
\c@maxextraname=\count121 \c@maxextradate=\count122
\c@maxextraalpha=\count123 \c@abbrvpenalty=\count124
\c@highnamepenalty=\count125 \c@lownamepenalty=\count126
\c@maxparens=\count127 \c@parenlevel=\count128 \blx@tempcnta=\count129
\blx@tempcntb=\count130 \blx@tempcntc=\count131
\blx@maxsection=\count132 \blx@maxsegment@0=\count133
\blx@notetype=\count134 \blx@parenlevel@text=\count135
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count136 \blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count137
\blx@entrysetcounter=\count138 \labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44 \biblabelsep=\skip45 \bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47 \bibinitsep=\skip48 \bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50 \blx@bcfin=\read1 \blx@bcfout=\write3
\blx@langwohyphens=\language82 \c@mincomprange=\count139
\c@maxcomprange=\count140 \c@mincompwidth=\count141 Package biblatex
Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model... Package biblatex
Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-dm.de f" File: blx-dm.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW) ) Package biblatex Info: Trying
to load biblatex custom data model... Package biblatex Info: ... file
'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found. \c@afterword=\count142
\c@savedafterword=\count143 \c@annotator=\count144
\c@savedannotator=\count145 \c@author=\count146
\c@savedauthor=\count147 \c@bookauthor=\count148
\c@savedbookauthor=\count149 \c@commentator=\count150
\c@savedcommentator=\count151 \c@editor=\count152
\c@savededitor=\count153 \c@editora=\count154
\c@savededitora=\count155 \c@editorb=\count156
\c@savededitorb=\count157 \c@editorc=\count158
\c@savededitorc=\count159 \c@foreword=\count160
\c@savedforeword=\count161 \c@holder=\count162
\c@savedholder=\count163 \c@introduction=\count164
\c@savedintroduction=\count165 \c@namea=\count166
\c@savednamea=\count167 \c@nameb=\count168 \c@savednameb=\count169
\c@namec=\count170 \c@savednamec=\count171 \c@translator=\count172
\c@savedtranslator=\count173 \c@shortauthor=\count174
\c@savedshortauthor=\count175 \c@shorteditor=\count176
\c@savedshorteditor=\count177 \c@labelname=\count178
\c@savedlabelname=\count179 \c@institution=\count180
\c@savedinstitution=\count181 \c@lista=\count182
\c@savedlista=\count183 \c@listb=\count184 \c@savedlistb=\count185
\c@listc=\count186 \c@savedlistc=\count187 \c@listd=\count188
\c@savedlistd=\count189 \c@liste=\count190 \c@savedliste=\count191
\c@listf=\count192 \c@savedlistf=\count193 \c@location=\count194
\c@savedlocation=\count195 \c@organization=\count196
\c@savedorganization=\count197 \c@origlocation=\count198
\c@savedoriglocation=\count199 \c@origpublisher=\count266
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count267 \c@publisher=\count268
\c@savedpublisher=\count269 \c@language=\count270
\c@savedlanguage=\count271 \c@origlanguage=\count272
\c@savedoriglanguage=\count273 \c@pageref=\count274
\c@savedpageref=\count275 \shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52 \shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54 \shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56 \locallabelnumberwidth=\skip57
\locallabelalphawidth=\skip58 \localshorthandwidth=\skip59
\localshortjournalwidth=\skip60 \localshortserieswidth=\skip61
\localshorttitlewidth=\skip62 \localshortauthorwidth=\skip63
\localshorteditorwidth=\skip64 Package biblatex Info: Trying to load
compatibility code... Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def'
found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\blx-compa t.def" File: blx-compat.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex compatibility (PK/MW) ) Package biblatex
Info: Trying to load generic definitions... Package biblatex Info: ...
file 'biblatex.def' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex. def" File: biblatex.def 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex compatibility (PK/MW)
\c@textcitecount=\count276 \c@textcitetotal=\count277
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count278 \c@biburlbigbreakpenalty=\count279
\c@biburlbreakpenalty=\count280 \c@biburlnumpenalty=\count281
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count282 \c@biburllcpenalty=\count283
\biburlbigskip=\muskip11 \biburlnumskip=\muskip12
\biburlucskip=\muskip13 \biburllcskip=\muskip14 \c@smartand=\count284
) Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style
'numeric'... Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.bbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\numer ic.bbx" File: numeric.bbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW) Package biblatex
Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'... Package biblatex
Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/bbx\stand ard.bbx" File: standard.bbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex bibliography style (PK/MW)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count285 \c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count286 )) Package
biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'... Package
biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/cbx\numer ic.cbx" File: numeric.cbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex citation style (PK/MW) Package biblatex
Info: Redefining '\cite'. Package biblatex Info: Redefining
'\parencite'. Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'. Package
biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'. Package biblatex Info:
Redefining '\smartcite'. Package biblatex Info: Redefining
'\supercite'. Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'. Package
biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'. Package biblatex Info:
Redefining '\cites'. Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'. ) Package biblatex
Info: Trying to load configuration file... Package biblatex Info: ...
file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex\biblatex. cfg" File: biblatex.cfg  )) Package csquotes Info: Checking for multilingual support... Package
csquotes Info: ... found 'babel' package. Package csquotes Info:
Adjusting default style. Package csquotes Info: Redefining alias
'default' -    'american'. Package biblatex Info: Trying to load
language 'american'
-    'american-apa'... Package biblatex Info: ... file 'american-apa.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex-apa\ameri can-apa.lbx" File: american-apa.lbx 2019/09/07 v8.0 APA biblatex localisation Package
biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'american'... Package biblatex
Info: ... file 'american.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\ameri can.lbx" File: american.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW) Package biblatex Info:
Trying to load language 'english'... Package biblatex Info: ... file
'english.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\engli sh.lbx" File: english.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW) )) Package biblatex
Info: Trying to load language 'american'... Package biblatex Info: ...
file 'american.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\ameri can.lbx" File: american.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW) Package biblatex Info:
Trying to load language 'english'... Package biblatex Info: ... file
'english.lbx' found.

("C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX
2.9\tex/latex/biblatex/lbx\engli sh.lbx" File: english.lbx 2019/08/31 v3.13a biblatex localization (PK/MW) ))) (test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
14. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 14. LaTeX Font
Info:    ... okay on input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking
defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    ...
okay on input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on
input line 14. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14. LaTeX
Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 14. LaTeX
Font Info:    ... okay on input line 14. Package biblatex Info: Input
encoding 'utf8' detected. Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding
selection. (biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `test.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data... Package biblatex Info: ... file 'test.bbl' found.  (test.bbl) Package
biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 14. Package biblatex
Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Akaike1973' on page 1 undefined on input line
17.


LaTeX Warning: Citation 'Akaike1987' on page 1 undefined on input line
18.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 21.

[1

{C:/Users/Msere/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
(test.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: (biblatex) test (biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'test.run.xml'. \openout1 = `test.run.xml'.

 )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  8819 strings out of 492450  163884 string characters out of 3120109  635904 words of
memory out of 3000000  13137 multiletter control sequences out of
15000+200000  3948 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for
9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  41i,4n,42p,795b,2345s
stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Users/Msere/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts /cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Users/Msere/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/type1/pu blic/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb    Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 24461 bytes). PDF statistics:  14 PDF objects out of
1000 (max. 8388607)  0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)  1
words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

`biber.log`

```
2019-11-20 19:58:51,210+0100 INFO  biber - starting with command line: biber test.tex
2019-11-20 19:58:51,281+0100 INFO  biber - installing package biber-windows-x64 triggered by biber/bin/windows-x64\biber.exe
2019-11-20 19:58:51,732+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: starting package maintenance...
2019-11-20 19:58:51,733+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: installation directory: "C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
2019-11-20 19:58:51,735+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: package repository: https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
2019-11-20 19:58:51,739+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: visiting repository https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/...
2019-11-20 19:58:51,740+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: repository type: remote package repository
2019-11-20 19:58:51,745+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: loading package repository manifest...
2019-11-20 19:58:51,756+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: downloading https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma...
2019-11-20 19:58:52,081+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: 0.19 MB, 4.93 Mbit/s
2019-11-20 19:58:52,238+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: package repository digest: 2ebce2d04b9f021330b1177167e766e4
2019-11-20 19:58:53,444+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: going to download 21368790 bytes
2019-11-20 19:58:53,445+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: going to install 3 file(s) (1 package(s))
2019-11-20 19:58:53,465+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: downloading https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma...
2019-11-20 19:59:06,672+0100 INFO  biber - mpm: 21.37 MB, 12.95 Mbit/s
2019-11-20 19:59:06,740+0100 FATAL biber - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2019-11-20 19:59:06,740+0100 FATAL biber - Info: keyName="biber-windows-x64"
2019-11-20 19:59:06,740+0100 FATAL biber - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Cfg\Cfg.cpp
2019-11-20 19:59:06,740+0100 FATAL biber - Line: 762
2019-11-20 19:59:06,746+0100 FATAL biber - The program 'biber' could not be found.
2019-11-20 19:59:06,746+0100 FATAL biber - Info: engine="exe", path="biber/bin/windows-x64/biber.exe", name="biber"
2019-11-20 19:59:06,746+0100 FATAL biber - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session\runperl.cpp
2019-11-20 19:59:06,746+0100 FATAL biber - Line: 53
```

After uninstalling MiKTeX and installing it again I have the following:

[image: MiKTeX immediately after it was installed and updated]

When I run in the command line `biber --version`, I have the following error:

> No such file or directory at /loader/HASH(0x6b4950)/PAR.pm line 1137.

After uninstalling Biber (the red line in the attached picture) I cannot install it again as it's shown in the picture.

[image: MikTeX after Biber (red line in previous picture) was removed]

When I go to the command line and I type `biber --version` I recive the following error:

```
starting package maintenance...
installation directory: "C:\Users\Msere\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9"
package repository: http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
package repository digest: c9ae9f64f80c574d433236a4b3975ad8
going to download 21368790 bytes
going to install 3 file(s) (1 package(s))
downloading http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/biber-windows-x64.tar.lzma...
21.37 MB, 21.01 Mbit/s

Unfortunately, the package biber-windows-x64 could not be installed.
Please check the log file:
```

When I try to uninstall Biber I have the following:[image: First thing that appears when I type biber --uninstall]

[image: Second thing that appears after type biber --uninstall]

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Twio questions: 1. Where is your .bib file. 2. Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> biber -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: Hi Bernard! Thanks for the answer. The .bib file is in the same folder that the main file (the .txt) and yes, I'm in texmaker doing the normal cycle. If you want any other reference let me know :)

Comment: I have no problem running this code. Could you post the `.blg` file?

Comment: What OS are you running? What is your TeX system (MikTeX or TeX Live?, version?)? When did you last update your system? Can you run Biber on your document from the command line and show the complete output you get *and* the `.blg` file?

Comment: and don't give us an image of the log, give us the real log, there is a log of valuable information in it.

Comment: I shared the log.file in the main post. My .blg file is completely blank (the size is actually 1kb). I can also share an screenshot but I don't think is going to contain any valuable information. I already tried uninstalling and installing again both, Texmaker and MiKTeX (my Tex system).

Comment: I shared the .log in the question, I hope is readable and understandable. It's the first time I ask a question here so I might have some errors in how to post.

Comment: The `.log` is probably largely irrelevant to this issue. As the question stands now the issue seems to be purely with Biber not starting correctly. The log tells me you are running a Windows OS and that you are using MikTeX. Can you run Biber on your document from the command line? Can you share the *complete* error message you get when you try to run `biber <filename>`? Does the same error occur when you run `biber --version` or `biber --help`? It is a long shot, but if you are lucky it may help to delete the Biber cache: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I run Biber with MiKTeX from a command line. The Biber.log was added to the original question.

Comment: That log looks as though MikTeX tries and fails to install Biber. Can you go to the MikTeX Console and check if Biber is installed? If not, try and to install it there. If it is installed, remove it and try to install it again via the Console.

Comment: I followed the suggestions and I updated the post with the current errors I had. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What antivirus are you running on Windows?  I once had a problem with Bitdefender silently blocking biber from running: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407200/111678

Comment: There seem to be at least two issues at play: MikTeX fails to install Biber in user mode and an installed Biber fails to run. Unfortunately, neither the Biber nor the MikTeX log show anything that would help me figure out where the issue lies. Uninstall Biber. Then install Biber in Admin mode (if you are admin). Then update MikTeX by running the Updater from the MikTeX Console ate least twice in Admin mode and then twice in user Mode. Delete the Biber cache (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140814/35864) try again. Check if an eager antivirus software interferes. ...

Comment: ... Biber unpacks itself (as an executable binary) into a temporary folder, maybe your antivirus finds that suspicious or access to the temporary folder is otherwise blocked (see for example https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/281, https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/70).

Comment: Hi. I'm using McAfee and although I disabled it the problem remains. In addition I cannot unintsall Bieber because when I do that I have the problem I show in the pictures I just added at the bottom of the question. I run it in Admin mode.

Comment: Please, any help on this?

Comment: You don't uninstall Biber by running `biber --uninstall`. You need to remove the Biber installation via the MikTeX Console in both admin and user mode. Then re-install in Admin mode.